# What is the meaning of {{each 'itemName'}} in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm reading through some javascript code for knockout.js. Could someone explain what is going on here? What does {{each seats}} signify in this case?

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="reservationTemplate">
    {{each seats}}
        <tr>
            <td>${name || 'Anonymous'}</td>
            <td>${meal().mealName}</td>
            <td>${meal().price}</td>                
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: That looks like some strange custom templating syntax for a `for` loop to me...

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the ["Templates" plug-in](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/). It's currently in "beta" status and as you can see from the notice at the top of that page, there's no plan to progress it beyond beta ([details](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/)). [`{{each}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/) is used for looping through the contents of an array, repeating the markup for each item.

Comment: Any reasons for it to not be developed further?

Comment: @peirix: I've added a link to the blog post where they explain this. There's also a brief explanation at the top of the templates page (the first link).

Answer (score 1):

{{each}} here is a template tag. See documentation for jQuery Templates: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ and this tag in particular: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/